# Cocoa App Sandbox - Error loading bundle

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, testing

I set up my app to use sandboxing and now I am not able to run my unit tests. I am getting this error message:

`objc[18812]: GC: forcing GC OFF because OBJC_DISABLE_GC is set
2012-06-14 09:19:42.689 Gitpilot[18812:603] Error loading /Users/corey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gitpilot-bedgmtkbdheptpbpjfklegmqyipi/Build/Products/Debug/GitpilotTests.octest/Contents/MacOS/GitpilotTests:  dlopen(/Users/corey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gitpilot-bedgmtkbdheptpbpjfklegmqyipi/Build/Products/Debug/GitpilotTests.octest/Contents/MacOS/GitpilotTests, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/corey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gitpilot-bedgmtkbdheptpbpjfklegmqyipi/Build/Products/Debug/GitpilotTests.octest/Contents/MacOS/GitpilotTests: open() failed with errno=1
IDEBundleInjection.c: Error loading bundle '/Users/corey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gitpilot-bedgmtkbdheptpbpjfklegmqyipi/Build/Products/Debug/GitpilotTests.octest'
2012-06-14 09:19:42.733 Gitpilot[18812:603] ApplePersistenceIgnoreState: Existing state will not be touched. New state will be written to /var/folders/rs/63y00fxj7dj07g91vrswhk240000gn/T/com.gitpilot.Gitpilot/com.gitpilot.Gitpilot.savedState`

I am using the SenTesting Framework with OCMock. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Turns out this is a bug in Apples sandboxd daemon. It prevent's the testing bundle from loading when entitlements are enabled.

Answer (score 12):

If you create a new build configuration in the project settings editor, you can go into the build settings tab and disable code signing and entitlements for just that configuration. Then, in the scheme editor, choose that configuration for unit testing, leaving your release and debug builds untouched while still being able to run unit tests.

Comment: +1 Empirically verified.  This should be noted as the correct answer.

Comment: That is, of course, assuming your unit tests don't require entitlements.  For instance, you won't be able to unit-test access to the group container.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in xcode 5. Turned out I had to disable the sandbox in the normal target before the test target would load correctly.